# How can I remove port from the endpoint?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, glassfish-3

I write a simple web service. After deploying my endpoint url is like this: http://MYCOMPUTER1:80/MyWebServices/MyService

```
@WebService(name="MyService", serviceName = "MyWebServices")
public interface IMyService{
// code
}
```

How can I remove port 80 from endpoit to get next url:
http://MYCOMPUTER1:80/MyWebServices/MyService

Answer (score 0):

Port 80 is the default port for http, so your endpoint will already work without specifying the port.  No need to do extra work to "remove" it.